# XSockets - custom controller is not registering

Tags: c#, javascript

I've been trying to evaluate XSockets but it appears I've hit my first stumbling block pretty early. I can connect to Generic controller just fine but custom controllers do not seem to work at all - I get a custom message: "The handler name was not found in loaded plugins". A Google search shows one other person having this problem in SE, but their solution did not work for me.

I've created a console project and installed the latest XSockets 3.03 from NuGet. My code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using XSockets.Core.Common.Socket;
using XSockets.Core.XSocket;
using XSockets.Core.XSocket.Helpers;
using XSockets.Core.Common.Socket.Event.Interface;

namespace XSockets2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var server = XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Composable.GetExport<IXSocketServerContainer>())
            {                
                Console.WriteLine("running!");
                server.StartServers();
                Console.ReadLine();
                server.StopServers();
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestCont: XSocketController
    {       
        public override void OnMessage(ITextArgs textArgs)
        {
            this.SendToAll(textArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

And my Javascript

```
    function connect2() {
                var host = "ws://localhost:4502/testcont";
                var conn;
                conn = new XSockets.WebSocket(host);   

                conn.on(XSockets.Events.open, function (clientInfo) {
                    message(clientInfo.ClientGuid); //appends message to textarea
                    console.log('Open', clientInfo);
                });

conn.on('OnMessage', function (d) {
                message(d);
                console.log('Message', d);
            });

            conn.on(XSockets.Events.onError, function (err) {
                message(err.CustomMessage);
                console.log('Error', err);
            });

            conn.on(XSockets.Events.close, function () {
                message('Closed');
                console.log('Closed');
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the latest version is 3.0.2 (not 3.0.3) but that is not important :)

There is a well known and documented bug in the plugin framework for the latest version. The bug only affect  you if you run a console application (or any other *.exe) project since xsockets by default only looks in *.dll and not *.exe.

The issue and work around is described [here](http://xsockets.net/docs/known-issues)

But your code will not work anyway since you have an error (from what I can see).
Your controller is named "TestCont" but you connect to "testcont". The connectionstring is case sensitive.

EDIT: I also think you are missunderstanding the method OnMessage since you have added a subscription to that exact name.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about this! I actually managed to make it work by using the fully qualified name ("Xsockets.TestCont") so I'm guessing the connection string being case sensitive was what threw me off.

Comment: @Uffe Do you know if this is still an issue? I'm on 3.0.5 and I'm having the same problem. It's gone from the known issues link and I can't search old issues to see the old workaround.

Comment: @JRoughan Hi, this should not be an issue. The server will look for plugins in both *.dll and *.exe by default now. I can take a look if you want?